# How To Fix This JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to add confirm box by using JavaScript. So, here is the code that I have used. When I click on the Delete button, it shows me a Confirmation message and when I click Ok, it doesn't delete my row.

What is wrong with this? How can I fix this?

[image: a table]

**Here is the Index Page**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row"> <!-- Start Of The Row Class -->
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
<br><br>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
include('ksdb.php');
// get results from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM academic")
or die(mysql_error());
?>
<table class='table table-bordered'>
<tr class='danger'> 
<th>ID</th> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Username</th> 
</tr>
<?php
// display data in table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
 ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
<td><a href="AdminChangePw.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" alt="edit" >Change</a></td>
 <td><a href="AdminEdit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" alt="edit" >Edit</a></td>
 <td><input type="button" onClick="deleteme(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)" name="Delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
<script language="javascript">
 function deleteme(delid)
 {
 if(confirm("Do you want Delete!")){
 window.location="AdminDel.php?id=' +id+'";
 return true;
 }
 } 
 </script>
<?php
}
?> 
 </table>
</div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->
</div> <!-- End Of The Row Class -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it removed from database?

Comment: @AdhershMNair - No..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the id to 'delid'. You are calling the function as `deleteme(delid)`.
So You Must use delid, instead of id.

```
 function deleteme(delid)
 {
 if(confirm("Do you want Delete!")){
 window.location.href="AdminDel.php?id="+delid; /*Change id to 'delid'*/
 return true;
 }
 }
```

Comment: I think there shouldn't be single quotes around `delid`. OP is validating ids with `is_numeric($_GET['id'])` so an id with single quotes won't be considered valid.

Comment: @AdhershMNair and Abhijit_Parida - Can I use this method to a link ??
echo '<td><a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="deleteme(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">Delete</a></td>';

Comment: I think you mean like this .. `<a id="myLink" href="AdminDel.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use
window.location.href
Instead of  window.location

Comment: But, What is the different between window.location.href and window.location ??

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your function:

```
function deleteme(delid) {
    if(confirm("Do you want Delete!")){
        window.location="AdminDel.php?id='+id+'";// this should be delid, also bad quotes, also you want to set the href, not the location
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fixed:

```
function deleteme(delid) {
    if(confirm("Do you want Delete!")){
        window.location.href="AdminDel.php?id=" + delid; 
        return true;
    }
}
```